# Trying to figure out how to add a link to access content in DIV created with JS

Tags: jquery, json

I am working with a JSON file in which I am pulling in data for a products page. I have a sidebar that has links to each product category (example tomatoes, olive oil, etc). I am using a click function for each link in the sidebar so that when they are clicked it shows the appropriate products in a DIV. My code works fine but I need assistance figuring out how to link to the generated DIV content from another page. In other words, it doesnt create a unique URL since its just replacing the DIV content.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  'use strict';

     var url = 'path to json';
    
     $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
   
   
   
    // initially display all products
    var categoryImage = '';
    var location;
    
    $.each(json, function (i, item) {
     
     categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="' + location + '">' + 
     '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
    });
    
    $('#imagesCategoryProducts').html(categoryImage); 
    
    
 
    // tomatoes display data on click
    $("#tomatoes").click(function(event){
     var categoryImage = '';
     var location;
    
     $.each(json, function (i, item) {
     
    
      if (item.itemCommodity == "1120") {
        categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="' + location + '">' + 
        '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
      }
     });
     $('#imagesCategoryProducts').html(categoryImage); 
    });
    
    
    
    // olive oil display data on click
    $("#oliveoil").click(function(event){
     var categoryImage = '';
     var location;
    
     $.each(json, function (i, item) {
      switch(item._id) 
     
    
      if (item.itemCommodity == "2120") {
        categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="' + location + '">' + 
        '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
      }
     });
     $('#imagesCategoryProducts').html(categoryImage); 
    });
  });
})();
</script>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("productsSideBar").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("productsSideBar").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
```

```css
/* Products Sidebar */

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
 z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

/* Products Sidebar Expand Button */

.expandSidebar {
 font-size:33px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-family: Quaddratt;
}

.backToSidebar {
 font-size:33px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-family: Quaddratt;
 color: #000;
}

.backToSiderbar a {
 color: #000;
}

.backToSiderbar a:hover {
 color: #333333;
}


/* Products Category Div Styles */

#imagesCategoryProducts h3 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 height: 40px;
}

#imagesCategoryProducts a {
 color: #000;
}

#imagesCategoryProducts a:hover {
 color: #333333;
}

/* Products Category Image Styles */

.productImagesCategory {
 width: 700px;
 margin-bottom: -20px;
 padding: 40px;
 height: 350px !important;
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="productsSideBar" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#" id="tomatoes">Tomatoes</a>
    <a href="#" id="sauce">Sauce</a>
    <a href="#" id="oliveoil">Olive Oil</a>
    <a href="#" id="redwinevinegar">Red Wine Vinegar</a>
    <a href="#" id="balsamicvinegar">Balsamic Vinegar</a>
    <a href="#" id="peppers">Peppers</a>
    <a href="#" id="artichokes">Artichokes</a>
    <a href="#" id="olives">Olives</a>
    <a href="#" id="beans">Beans</a>
    <a href="#" id="caperspignolinuts">Capers & Pignoli Nuts</a>
    <a href="#" id="specialties">Specialties</a>
    <a href="#" id="spices">Spices</a>
    <a href="#" id="fish">Fish</a>
    <a href="#" id="brothstockssoups">Broth, Stocks & Soups</a>
    <a href="#" id="breadcrumbs">Breadcrumbs</a>
    <a href="#" id="gratedcheese">Grated Cheese</a>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Products Products Row -->     
<section> 
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
              <br>
                <span class="expandSidebar" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Filter by Category</span>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12"> 
              <div id="imagesCategoryProducts"></div> 
             </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</section>
<!-- Products Row End -->
```

Comment: If you want a unique page to link to why not just make normal pages for each category and link to those?

Comment: i could do that but im trying to avoid creating a ton of different pages. i have like 40+ product categories and i figured doing it dynamically would be easier and easier to update as a whole

Comment: If you really want to avoid the extra pages and be able to load categories from a unique link I think you need to use a query string. `/page?category=tomatoes` and then run a script on page load that grabs the category and runs the code.

Comment: can you give me an example? like do i need to add that into the on click function?

Comment: Post some snippets or plnkr to get better/quicker help.

Comment: @bhantol posted it thanks. only thing i didnt include was the json but you get the point. once the sidebar item is clicked, the page content changes and pulls in the correct products that correspond to the category.

Comment: Your Javascript has error `switch(item._id)` but may not be what is causing it. Creating a plunkr for you - posting it shortly.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out its old code

Comment: Here is https://plnkr.co/edit/85Fl8fgZKHsou22khqb5?p=preview

Comment: However when you click on `#tomatoes` you are setting the same contents again/ At this the json object probably does not ave anything in it. I suggest you move the click() handler out of getJSON

Comment: thanks @bhantol the code I had actually functioned before the same way. what I meant to say in the question is that say i include this sidebar on another page (without all the json etc) how can i then link to the tomatoes category and have it display from a different page? does that make sense?

Comment: What is `page` ? New browser window/tab? or Another div ?

Comment: the actual item page itself. say if you click on the tomatoes category and then click on the first item in the div. it will open up a single item page of that type of tomato. now from that page i need to be able to include the same sidebar but without all the previous json etc. i just want a way to jump back to the categories that correspond to the items

Comment: but im facing an issue because as you know, the div is being populated dynamically. theres no way to link to the generated content because when you click on the tomatoes tab, olives tab etc. it doesnt create a unique page url. it just overwrites the content on the same page and i have no way of linking to it from another page or href without loading the entire product categories page itself

Comment: Here https://plnkr.co/edit/Sl1vFH6W40PVf7ooleU7?p=preview This shows Green Tomatoes on page load and when you click on Tomatoes it shows Red tomatoes.

Comment: @Tom No. In the other page you format the link like I showed, then when you arrive at that link call the function (it needs to be named so you can trigger it without going through the click) and pass it the category so that it knows what to show.

Comment: @dlsso can you create a small snippet? im having a hard time grasping how to do this. pretty new to jquery js

Comment: The posted answer works.

Comment: thanks bhantol. so if I have a totally new html page (aside from the current one) and include that sidebar, the links will take me to the correct category on a new page? without including all the json etc on the new page (just the sidebar)

Comment: Its a same page. It just replaces your `<div id="imagesCategoryProducts"></div> ` on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to store that json into `data` variable as soon as you perform `getJSON`.

The click handler for `#tomatoes` now uses the `data` object which is now available vs in the posted code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Sl1vFH6W40PVf7ooleU7?p=preview

You can do the apply the same logic for other caregories.